# Metadata could not be determined in SSIS OLEDB source

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, sql-server-2012, oledb

I am trying to use dynamic query inside `OLEDB source`, but getting

> "Metadata could not be determined" error which is usual.

I used `WITH RESULT SET` (in SQL Server 2012) inside the Stored procedure to fix the issue, but the actual source is SQL Server 2005 where this fix is not working.

Is there any other way this can be resolved in 2005?

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666817/using-dynamic-sql-in-an-ole-db-source-in-ssis-2012 ?

Comment: Yes, no solution for 2005.

Comment: I know this has been asked and answered for 2005 before, but I can't find it right away.   Basically it's this answer:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/18360265/1507566